# Calculating average in distriubtion

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a table with the below information:

Holding Period is computed as # of days between Start & End Dates

```
   ID   Start_Date   End_Date   Reading    Holding_Period   

   1     20140501     20160410    55        710
   2     20150407     20151231    82        268
   3     20160104     20160529    110       146
   4     20140209     20160209    39        730
   5     20131211     20151101    25        690
```

For this data set, I am getting the frequency distribution and average holding-period (hp) using the below.

```
 select YEAR(enddate)*100 + MONTH(enddate) as salemonth
 ,avg(hp) as hp
 ,sum(reading_0_50) as reading_0_50
 ,sum(reading_50_100) as reading_50_100
 ,sum(reading_100_150) as reading_100_150 
 from
 (
  select x.id
  ,x.enddate as enddate
  ,sum(x.hp) as hp
  ,sum(x.reading_0_50) as reading_0_50
  ,sum(x.reading_50_100) as reading_50_100
  ,sum(x.reading_100_150) as reading_100_150
  from
  (  select id
     ,hp
     ,enddate
     ,case when reading >= 0 and reading <= 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as   reading_0_50
     ,case when reading > 50 and reading<= 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  as reading_50_100
     ,case when reading > 100 and reading<= 150 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as reading_100_150
   from readings
  )x
  group by x.id,x.enddate
 ) p
 group by YEAR(enddate)*100 + MONTH(enddate)
```

This gives me the output

```
 salemonth  hp  reading_0_50    reading_50_100  reading_100_150

 201511    690    1                 0             0
 201512    268    0                 1             0
 201602    730    1                 0             0
 201604    710    0                 1             0
 201605    146    0                 0             1
```

However the Average HP is across the month

My question is: . , if I were to get the average HP by the Binned Bucket, how do I do that in SQL?

Thanks in advance for reading.

Comment: In your innermost query you are defining the buckets by hit count. Define the buckets again, but return HP else 0 instead. Then AVG() them in the next queries.

Comment: Thanks @Malk for responding. You mean adding these right:   ,case when reading >= 0 and reading <= 50 THEN hp ELSE 0 END as hp_reading_0_50
         ,case when reading > 50 and reading<= 100 THEN hp ELSE 0 END  as hp_reading_50_100
         ,case when reading > 100 and reading<= 150 THEN hp ELSE 0 END as hp_reading_100_150 .  I tried that earlier, wasn't getting the right average values. So, wondering what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select YEAR(enddate)*100 + MONTH(enddate) as salemonth
 ,avg(hp) as hp
 ,sum(reading_0_50_count) as reading_0_50
 ,sum(reading_50_100_count) as reading_50_100
 ,sum(reading_100_150_count) as reading_100_150 
 ,case when sum(reading_0_50_count) = 0 then 0 else sum(reading_0_50_total) / sum(reading_0_50_count) end as reading_0_50_avg
 ,case when sum(reading_50_100_count) = 0 then 0 else sum(reading_50_100_total) / sum(reading_50_100_count) end as reading_50_100_avg
 ,case when sum(reading_100_150_count) = 0 then 0 else sum(reading_100_150_total) / sum(reading_100_150_count) end  as reading_100_150_avg
 from
 (
  select x.id
  ,x.enddate as enddate
  ,sum(x.hp) as hp
  ,sum(x.reading_0_50_count) as reading_0_50_count
  ,sum(x.reading_50_100_count) as reading_50_100_count
  ,sum(x.reading_100_150_count) as reading_100_150_count
  ,sum(x.reading_0_50_total) as reading_0_50_total
  ,sum(x.reading_50_100_total) as reading_50_100_total
  ,sum(x.reading_100_150_total) as reading_100_150_total
  from
  (  select id
     ,hp
     ,enddate
     ,case when reading >= 0 and reading <= 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as   reading_0_50_count
     ,case when reading > 50 and reading<= 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  as reading_50_100_count
     ,case when reading > 100 and reading<= 150 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as reading_100_150_count

     ,case when reading >= 0 and reading <= 50 THEN hp ELSE 0 END as   reading_0_50_total
     ,case when reading > 50 and reading<= 100 THEN hp ELSE 0 END  as reading_50_100_total
     ,case when reading > 100 and reading<= 150 THEN hp ELSE 0 END as reading_100_150_total
   from readings
  )x
  group by x.id,x.enddate
 ) p
 group by YEAR(enddate)*100 + MONTH(enddate)
```